# Live server vs code is not working and any of the solutions work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have downloaded live server but it is not working. It doesn't show me any error messages like it does to others. I tried reinstalling it, I tried reinstalling vs code too, but nothing happened. I see from people which have it working that it displays on the tab of the IDE but for me it’s not there. I try to open it with right-clicking on one of the HTML files but nothing happens. I also checked my default browser and added it to the json.file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to install an earlier version of the live server extension and it worked.